# Footer's background pattern gets cuttoff when window is resized

Tags: css, css-float, margin, footer

So most of this site so far uses auto centering (the container and nav have margin-left/right:auto) and things seem to go all well and dandy except for the footer.

When I resize the size of the window everything is filled nicely except when I scroll horizontally the footer seems to be cut off on the right side.I've read that this may be a browser bug. Though it occurs in IE and chrome and firefox so it could just be sloppy coding (I am a big newb).

Here is the css:

```
 #footer {
background-image:url(../Images/footer_bg.jpg);
color: white;
height:300px;
padding-top:20px;
 }


 /*I have 4 headings with Ps that I want to display horizontally side by side*/
#footerContent{
   min-width:1000px;    
   }

/*So I tried floating <li> inside <ul> and limiting its width, which worked fine */
    #footerContent ul{
        width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }

#footerContent li {float:left; width:250px;  }
```

Just to reiterate it works fine when the browser is full screened or resized. But after you resize and you use the horizantal scrollbar to scroll all the way right then the background image is cut off.

I've tried width:100%, min-width, width:1000px; but none of those seemed to work.

http://postimage.org/image/3so264fnb/

Comment: Upload your site on a live server and give us a link to it for checking the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding your comment about Stackoverflow being similar

(at least as of 4-29-2012)

The issue on stackoverflow seems to be that the `footer` contains another `div` element, `footerwrap`, that has a `width: 960px` set to it, but `footer` itself has no width setting. A `div` is [basically designed to simply "group" block level content](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements). It is a common misconception that a `div` expands with it's content. Actually, a `div` expands to its parent *if an explicit `width` is set on a parent*. If there is none, then it fits the *browser window*. This is what you (and stackoverflow) is experiencing.

To get the `div` to relate to the content `width`, you must either:

1. Explicitly set the `width` or `min-width` of the container. So, if stackoverflow set a `min-width: 990px` (the 960px of the footerwrap + the padding of 15px on each side) on the `footer` that wraps `footerwrap`, then its problem is solved.
2. Set the container `div` to `float`, as a floated element wraps its content.

Take a look at [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RU9pX/13/). Note the first two div's experience the same issue you are seeing. If you shrink or expand the size of the iframe window in the fiddle, the first two div's will contract or enlarge with it, but still leave blank space on the horizontal scroll. The third and fourth div's have had my fixes above applied. The fifth div is to show the fact that the inner div, if not defined in width, will expand to the width of a container that has an explicit `width` set.

As a side note, it may work (I have not tested in many browsers, but FF 11 worked) to actually just add a `float: left` to the `body` element in those cases where the `body` does not have a set width. As [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RU9pX/14/) shows, it seems to be effective in causing the first two div's to behave just like the 3rd and 4th divs.

I hope this helps.

**Original Answer**

It is a little unclear what can be done because there is some information lacking. Here are some things to look for:

1. Is your `background-image` wide enough (or can it / should it have a `background-repeat: repeat-x` applied to make it wider if needed)?
2. Does your footer width (`1000px`) match your upper content width? If footer is constrained narrower than what the upper content area (or header, etc.) is allowed to be, then it's background will not align.

That's the best I can do without seeing more of your html and css for the page, and not knowing the size of the image and your intention for how it is to function.

Comment: Sorry for not providing more info, my site is not live yet and the entire code is too long to post. Actually.... THIS page itself has the same problem. If you look at stackoverflow's footer page at the bottom it's grey and filled out right? But try resizing the window. When it's smaller and you see the horizantal scroll bar move it to the right and the footer is cut off! That's the exact same problem I have!I'm using google chrome v18.

Comment: Just to add, my footer div is outside of any other container so the width is set to 100%, it adjusts to the page width. I have set a pattern to it as well. The bug seems to occur even without the pattern...It's a bit of a shame because I don't want to disable horizantal scrolling either (But maybe I should).

Comment: @notcrazy--Added an update to my answer based on the stackoverflow example. It should help guide you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I've since asking that question learned a freaking ton by writing up the other pages of the site. It turns out there was a stray } (or two) in my css file... And for some reason I did not realize that I had an absolute property hiding in the code (Because of the stray }'s an absolute property from another element must've snuck in. Problem solved!

Comment: @notcrazy--glad you solved it. Often the best way to learn is to do!