# Using CSS, how can I style a div tag to full the <body> width, even when the viewport is scaled?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }

        body, div, span, applet, object, embed, iframe, pre, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, b, strong, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, sub, sup, tt, var, table, tbody, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, button, label, legend, caption, hr, noscript {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: none;
            list-style: none;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-family: inherit;
            vertical-align: top;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
        }

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
            top: 0;
            font: 12px/1.3 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #131318;
            background: #E7E7E7;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .full {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }

        .top {
            padding: 20px 0;
            background: #FF0000;
        }

        .center {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .shell {
            width: 860px;
            padding: 20px;
            float: left;
            background: #FFF;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="full top">logo</div>
        <div class="full">
            <div class="center">
                <div class="shell">
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                    <p>Lorem</p>
                </div><!--/.shell-->
            </div><!--/.center-->
        </div><!--/.full-->
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see in [here](http://cl.ly/image/421z26151n1O) (or by visiting [here](http://jsbin.com/aqeqaj) and shrinking your browser down until there is a horizontal scroll bar, then scrolling to the right) that the top red bar is always the size of the viewport, rather than filling up the entire width of the page. How can I fix this? How can I make a bar like this (my header with menu, etc.) truly fill the width of the page, regardless of view-port resizing (preferably without JavaScript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked many times. The consensus seems to be to set a min-width on the div.

```
min-width: 960px;
```

Other discussions:

- [100% width div gets cut off when I scroll right if my browser window is smaller than div's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554813/100-width-div-gets-cut-off-when-i-scroll-right-if-my-browser-window-is-smaller)
- [scrollbar cutting off div background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724791/scrollbar-cutting-off-div-background)
- [Footer's background pattern gets cuttoff when window is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360936/footers-background-pattern-gets-cuttoff-when-window-is-resized)

Comment: Zomg, thanks! Last time I was heavy into CSS, you couldn't rely on `min-width` (IE6, etc.). That's a life-saver!